# Get checkbox value from view to controller using formcollection - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Code in View

```
<input type="checkbox" value="@Model.Employee.IsActive" name="chkIsActive" id="chkIsActive" @(Model.Employee.IsActive == true ? "checked" : "") />
```

Code in controller Action method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateMaster(FormCollection collection)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(collection["chkIsActive"]);
        }
```

I have also tried this way

```
rate.IsActive = collection["chkIsActive"] == "on" ? true : false;
```

It is giving me value as "value" instead of true false. Can somebody guide me?
Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `FormCollection` and manually generating the html. Use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive)` and change the POST method to `public ActionResult UpdateMaster(Employee model)` - its all done out of the box and you get true 2-way model binding. One issue with your current code is that unchecked checkboxes do not post back so it simply wont exist unless the checkbox is checked when you submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your reply, that's correct but I want to know that how can I work this way?

Comment: Read the second part of my comment - `chkIsActive` will not exist in `FormCollection` if the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: But it is not giving me any value even if it is checked

Comment: `string cb = collection["chkIsActive"];` returns `"on"` for me if the value of `IsActive` is `false`, otherwise it returns `"value"`

Comment: If you changed it to `value="@Model.Employee.IsActive.ToString()"` it should return `"True"` if checked

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks buddy, Now on this earth I am using m=>m.IsActive hahaha Many thanks. And +1 for your first comment.